# Can Two Electromagnetic waves cancel each other if it 180 degree phase moving in same direction?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, photon-emission

If we can send two electromagnetic waves -180 degree out of phase-  in same direction, then the interaction of this wave with air molecules will be less due to the low intensity of the combination. So, we can reduce the distortion for the transmitted signals. Is this conclusion right?

Comment: You should specify a bit more clearly what you call "interaction". As it is, the only thing I understand is this context is the optical index, which depends on the frequency, but has a small effect on the celerity and none on the magnitude of both electric and magnetic fields.

Comment: I mean the spatial inhomogeneity of the air refractive index.

Comment: Sending two waves in the same direction that are 180 degrees out of phase is the same as sending one lower amplitude wave.

Comment: A common example of this is [antireflection coatings](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/antireflection-coating)

Comment: I would say your conclusion is wrong. But mainly because there are a lot of problems with your argument. Lets assume that you "send" 2 EM waves with the same wavelength but make them 180° out of phase and they both have the same amplitude. You can only do this with an interferometer, and you will not send anything in that direction because you will divert all the power to the other output arm of your interferometer. ie there is no power in the arm you want to use, its all in the other one.

Comment: @JoséAndrade thanks. Your answer is very useful. So, is there a way that we can determine in which arm of interferometer will send zero energy? or it will be interference pattern in both arms of the interferometer?